# Creating Linux Service for Cassandra DDAC

Tags: linux, cassandra

**Creating Linux service for  DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra (DDAC)**

Hi,

Installed DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra (DDAC), the Cassandra community version by DataStax.
Used this link:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddac/doc/datastax_enterprise/install/installDDAC.html

At the end of the instructions, it says to start Cassandra using interactive command, not as a service:

$ bin/cassandra

Also, there is NO option to create a service for Cassandra using:

$ service cassandra start

I get:

Failed to start cassandra.service: Unit not found.

Does DDAC support starting as a service?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are right, DDAC has those instructions to launch the process from command line, if you want to set it as a service, my guess is that Datastax will provide it as part of their enterprise product.

You can still create the systemd service unit, there are multiple examples in github like [this one](https://gist.github.com/tobert/8202635)